# How to create a search engine(similar to a Command F function) in MATLAB?

Tags: list

I have a project where I have to write a script in MATALAB which basically takes in a very big spreadsheet of data and allows the user to be able to quickly find keywords when searched for. They also want the script to display how many times the keyword shows up and they want specific keywords to be groups under a specific group and so.

P.S. I'm only an intern here with barely any MATLAB experience. They didn't have anyone else to do this project so they assigned it to me despite me telling them I'm not good at MATLAB.